# Adding days to Moment object (momentjs)

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm trying to find a way to add days to a moment. I can get it to work for a moment based on the current time, but that's it. Here my current code:

```
let start = moment('2017-01-15');
console.log(moment().add(7, 'days'));
console.log(moment(start).add(7, 'days'));
```

This is what get as the result:

> Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _isUTC: false, _pf: Object, _locale:
>   Locale, _d: Mon Mar 13 2017 12:21:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight
>   Time)…}
>
> Moment {_isAMomentObject: true, _i: "2017-01-15", _f: "YYYY-MM-DD",
>   _isUTC: false, _pf: Object…}

So it works on moment() but not that's it. Everywhere I look, that's how I'm supposed to do it so I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: So it looks like I have to use format() to even see the change. Odd, but it seems to work.

Comment: same with me: I tried it on their Moment.js own [website](https://momentjs.com/docs/). If I did `moment('2017-01-15').add(7, 'days')` it would still output the same date, but if I did `moment('2017-01-15').add(7, 'days').format()` it would show the new date with the days added, as expected.
I also noticed (just like you did) that _this only happened if I passed a date string as a param_. If I just did `moment().add(7, 'days')` it would output as expected. Must have something to do with how Moment.js stores date variables?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You already created the `moment` object, now you can call `add` with `start` variable.

```js
let start = moment('2017-01-15');
console.log(moment().add(7, 'days'));
console.log(start.add(7, 'days'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  top: 0;
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: The second date is still the same.

Comment: @TroyTaylor No it's not. It says, "2017-01-22".

Comment: +1 for `start.add(7, 'days')` instead of `moment(start)`, but I suggest to use [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) method  to show moment values.